# Issue with RackTables Browser Install

Tags: php

I am currently working on a project of installing a RackTables application. I started off by building a LAMP Server on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I followed the instructions from the [RackTables Wiki](http://wiki.racktables.org/index.php/RackTablesInstallHowto).
When it came to the part of browser install where one enters *http://ip.address/racktables*, the web server shows directory paths and folders instead of RackTables installation steps of 1 - 6.

Any ideas on what I missed out? Your response and assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have other PHP pages working on your box? Does the directory it's showing you contain css/, js/, pix/, inc/ and index.php?